# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int' Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

I'm trying to follow along with Blackthornprods inventory tutorial. I have run into some problems when trying to insert the button item inside the inventory slot.

Here is my code

[image]

Comment: Please insert the code as text, not as an image. There's no IDE that I know of that can parse images.

Comment: Specifically, can we see the Inventory class?

Comment: Without the definition of inventory its very hard for you to get an accurate answer as there could be many guesses, please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`inventory.slots` returns a single instance of GameObject, not a collection. So, trying to access the i-element of inventory results in an error.

Go to the definition of `Inventory` class and makes sure that "slots" is declared as `public name-of-the-class[] slots` and not `public name-of-the-class slots` (without square brackets).